# Encrypted partition on Debian requiring multiple keys to unlock

Tags: lvm, luks

The title pretty much sums it up, but I want to create a second data partition on a web-facing server which is encrypted and requires two people to provide passphrases before it can be unlocked. Is this even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38387/are-there-more-advanced-luks-key-schemes-e-g-2-of-3-keys-needed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that LUKS is ready for it.

But you can make a password that is just two passwords concatenated. Or have encrypted partitionfile on encrypted partition..

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - it needs to be 2 out of a possible 4 passphrases (any combination of 2 of the 4 need to work).